# Autobuild option in vscode like in eclipse

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I'm working a project which has been developed in eclipse, but to be honest I don't like ecplipse very much, that's why I'm trying to use vscode but I have a problem which I'm unable to solve.

Just a little bit more Info we are working with Maven and Tomcat for this project.

The issue that I have is that when I make a change of the frontend in the src/webapp, VSCODE doesn't update the tomcat automatically, I have to serve the project once again, there is any way to just autobuild option like in eclipse?

Comment: We can run war package on Tomcat server, so any code changes, it's required to regenerate war package, then deploy it to tomcat server. If you want the autobuild feature, you may file a feature request in [github/vscode-maven](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-maven/issues).

Comment: so then, as far I understood there is no workaround, I already created a feature request, let's see what they answer :) thank you!

Comment: I believe this is the feature request https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-maven/issues/752